# Listing Articles and Videos together

Tags: lists, content, video

On the landing screen of an App, we have content separated into two tabs, News / Videos.  I am trying to see if it makes more sense to have News Articles and Videos presented together, using icons to indicate which are vides and which are articles.

What is the benefit of having them mixed together and what are the benefits of having them separated into Tabs?  I feel it helps the user drill into the specific kind of content they want when they are in tabs.  But it might allow for more discovery having them presented together.

Any hard evidence as to which could be better?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the benefit out of all of this is to user test! Yay to user testing!

You can present both, because as you said, it allows for more discovering and it really comes down to what your stakeholders (base users) want. For instance, let's take the site Polygon for example. They are a prime example of combination of videos and articles together.

http://www.polygon.com/

The biggest thing about their site is that their content is all tied to one concept. Gaming.

Another thing you should also be VERY aware of is how your information architecture is tied up. Polygon has reviews, news, opinion and the like, but not all of them are articles. Some of them are video based and while others are written content.

Same with www.cracked.com (not the best of examples... Polygon is better).

It's all about information architecture and how you deliver the content through aesthetic means.

Good luck!